# Iterator arithmetic

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

In c++ STL, if I have an iterator `it` into a vector `v`, is `it - v.begin()` guaranteed to give me the index into the vector, so that `*it == v[it - v.begin()]`? If so, is this true for all random access iterators?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is, and it is true for all RA iterators.

Comment: Table 76 in the C++03 standard provides the requirements for random access iterators that make the relationship guarantees.